# Python: returning None instead of False

Tags: python, list

The below code is returning `None` instead of `False`. Please help me understand the reason.

```
def same_first_last(nums):
    for i in nums:
        if nums[0] == nums[-1] and len(nums) >= 1:
            return True
        else:
            return False


print(same_first_last([]))
```

Any help is appreaciated !!!

Comment: Because your input list is empty and it never even goes into the loop.

Comment: Why are you using a loop at all? You never use `i`, and you return immediately from the first iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two scenarios based on your question: -

1. Size of `nums` > 0:

   If `nums` list is non-empty, then it will either satisfy your `if` condition i.e `nums[0] == nums[-1] and len(nums) >= 1` in which case it will return `True` or else it will return `False`
2. Size of `nums` == 0

   If this is the case then code doesn't even go inside the `for` loop in which case It will not be able to go inside the `if else` block, that's why python returns `None` by default, so your code is also returning None.

   To avoid this you can change the code as below:- ( You don't even need to go inside the for loop as your `if else` conditions are static i.e not changing with the iterator `i` from the `for` loop of your question.

```
def same_first_last(nums):
    return nums and nums[0] == nums[-1]

print(same_first_last([]))
```

here in the above `return nums and nums[0] == nums[-1]`, it a join of two conditions `if nums` and `if nums[0] == nums[-1]`

a) `if nums` is checking if the list or the string you are iterating is empty or not. If empty it return `False` else `True`

b) `if nums[0] == nums[-1]`: - It's checking for the condition from your question (checking if the front element and the last element are equal or not)

When both the above conditions met, then only it will return True or else it will return False

Comment: `return nums and nums[0] == nums[-1]`…

Comment: @AlokRaj yes i did

Answer (score 0):

Since you are calling your method with an empty list, you are never entering the for-loop in your method and therefor you can never reach your return-statement. when your method is called with an empty List, your for-loop is skipped completely. You can change your method like this:

```py
def same_first_last(nums): 
    for i in nums: 
        if nums[0] == nums[-1] and len(nums) >= 1: 
            return True
        else:
            return False
    return <enter default value here>
```

But you dont even need the loop, so you can simplify your code even a little bit more:

```py
def same_first_last(nums): 
    if len(nums) > 0: 
        return nums[0] == nums[-1]
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: `if len(nums) > 0` can even be simplified to `if nums`.

Comment: oh nice, I did not know that. But maybe for a beginner `len(nums) > 0` is more understandable.

Comment: Thank you for clariffication, it works properly now :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not entering the loop, so the function effectively has no return value. This can be verified by printing something inside the loop:

```
def same_first_last(nums):
    for i in nums:
        print("in the loop")
        if nums[0] == nums[-1] and len(nums) >= 1:
            return True
        else:
            return False


print(same_first_last([]))
```

You can actually make this code work by swapping the conditions in the if() statement and removing the for loop like so:

```
def same_first_last(nums):
    return len(nums) >= 1 and nums[0] == nums[-1]

print(same_first_last([]))
```

Comment: or just `return len(nums) > 1 and nums[0] == nums[-1]:`

Comment: `if expr: return True else: return False` is pretty much always redundant and overly verbose and can be reduced to `return expr`…